# Powerpoint - VBA - Run Application CommandBars

Tags: vba, powerpoint, commandbar

I want to create a macro which allows, once an object is selected, to open the associated CommandBar.

I wrote the following which works sometimes, but not everytime - it does not work the first time. and I do not understand why. I have to manually do a right click and select the "Height and position" option to run it for the first time and then everything works - the formatting pane is displayed.

Do you have any clues to avoid the right click part?

```
Sub Bars ()
  Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = True
End Sub
```

This is Office 2016.

[image: Outpout]
Other code tested:

```
Sub Bars ()
  On Error GoTo Out
  Dim cmd As CommandBar
  For Each cmd In Application.CommandBars
    cmd.Enabled = True
  Next
  If Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = True Then
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
  Else
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = True
  End If
Out:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite possibly, the reason the code is not working as expected is because PowerPoint 2016 (as all versions for the last 12 years or so) no longer uses `CommandBars` for the user interface. It can work, but it's better to use the Ribbon whenever possible.

In order to trigger a built-in command, it's possible to use the `idMSO` "name" of the command. A complete list of these commands can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745).

Searching the list for **Format** turns up the idMSO `ObjectFormatDialog`. Testing on my system using the following line displays the `Format Shape` task pane:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("ObjectFormatDialog")
```

The "Mso" methods are the only things `CommandBars` are used for, these days...

Answer (score -1):

Commandbars were deprecated with the introduction of Office 2007, more than 12 years ago. Sometimes it's necessary to run CommandBarButton.Execute to run a command that isn't in the object model. Other than that, you should be looking into ribbon modification to display custom commands.